# Remove blog folder name when keep wordpress inside cakephp webroot

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp

Due to some requirement I have to install wordpress in cakephp site, I installed it inside app/webroot/blog and after some modification I can access wordpress blog as 
mysite.com/blog

Now the problem is that wordpress post url should not contain word "blog" ,currently they are as

mysite.com/blog/post_url.

They should be like

mysite.com/post_url.

I have open to install wordpress anywhere.

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you truly don't want the word 'blog' to appear in the url, or that you can't see your posts because their path is wrong?  If the latter, you can fix it by changing the root path in the wordpress settings, add '/blog' at the end of your default path and all should be well.